# How to set different variation depends on different iPhone devices?

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface

I'm new to Swift programming and I want to know how people adapt to different sizes of the iPhone screen.

If I understand correctly, all of the portrait iPhone devices (like iPhone 4 to iPhone 11) have compact width and regular height. So, I cannot vary the size of UIs depends on the iPhone devices. The images below are something I'm working on as for my personal project, however, since I cannot change the size of UI depending on iPhone devices, I can't see a button when I change the device to iPhone 4 and the text fields are too big for both iPhone SE and iPhone 4.

iPhone 11

[image]

iPhone SE

[image]

iPhone 4

[image]

It is possible for me to resize the UIs for iPhone 4 or iPhone SE, but it's gonna make UIs for iPhone 8, 10, 11 too small.
I saw some people ask this question on Google, but the answers were for adding variation to different size of width and height, which was not I was looking for.

I want to know how I can make UI changes for different iPhone devices (which all of them are the same compact width and regular height), and also want to know how developers adapt to universal design (I mean my UIs for iPhone 4 and iPhone 11 are very different). I hope not many people use iPhone 4 anymore, but I was so confused now...

Also, is it better to make UIs with the smallest screen size first? So, in my case, make UIs with iPhone 4 first (which I don't think many people are using) in order to avoid UI problems like me.

BTW, I'm using the storyboard, for now, not Swift UI.

Comment: search adding constraints to View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Auto Layout & constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html) to automatically calculate the position of elements based on the screen size and defined rules.

I'm not entirely sure what the view should look like across all devices but I will give an example. Since you have 3 textfields and 1 button next to each other, you can put them in a vertical stackview and then put that stackview within another stackview along with the image and apply the constraint directly to the parent stackview. For example, center it in the view.

So it will look like this:

- View

  - Vertical Stackview - Apply H/W center constraint on this

    - Image
    - Vertical Stackview

      - Textfield
      - Textfield
      - Textfield
      - Button

By using two stackviews you can then define one spacing between the input elements and have a larger space between the Image and the inputs stackview.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1j-Frd5snYc) video seems like it is a good introduction to constraints.

Comment: Thank you, Bailey. I used auto layout & constraints in this project. I was also researching this problem, but I now think the problem is I added fixed sizes to all of UIs I currently have. For example, I added font size 60 to the label, "If-then scheduler", so it takes a large space and put other text field and button way below when I use iPhone SE or iPhone 4. I also added w:250 and h: 58 to each text field, so I think that's why cause this problem. How do you add the width and the size of UI when you work on Swift programming? Probably people don't add a fixed number to its width and height.

Comment: I was looking for a resizable UI but could not find a good example yet...
So sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: You can add the size in the same popup as the constraints. You can also select the size constraint in the document outliner and then click on the size inspector to change `equals` to `greater than or equal to` to prevent a element from becoming to small.